# Is there is a way to get the month end date for every month

Tags: sql, db2

How to get the current month end date through db2 query. 
I should not need to modify the query for every month

Every month the sql is executing so it need to automatically take care

Comment: Do you know about `CURRENT DATE`?

Comment: The subject of your question contradicts with its contents. Do you need `values CURRENT DATE` or end date of current month?

Comment: Get the date corresponding to the first day of the next month, and subtract one day.

Comment: can you please give me the query

Comment: You should always put the Db2-version and Db2-server operating-system (linux/unix/windows,  i-series,  z/os )  when asking for help with Db2. The reason is that the answer can depend on these facts.

Answer (score 1):

In Db2 11.1 this could be a solution:

```
select next_month(current date) - 1 day from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Next_Month will return the first day of the next month from the data provided.

Comment: I am getting the error
QUERY MESSAGES:                                                          
NO FUNCTION BY THE NAME NEXT_MONTH HAVING COMPATIBLE ARGUMENTS WAS FOUND

Answer (score 1):

SELECT LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE) AS LASTDAY 
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;

The query is working

### LASTDAY

2019-04-30

Answer (score 1):

The old way would be

```
CURRENT DATE - (DAY(CURRENT DATE)) DAYS + 1 MONTH
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last day of the current month, use this:

```
SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))
```

This will format the date for you

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE, 12)
```

See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for more information regarding the '12'. 12 is the right code

Another solution is to use TIMESTAMP_FORMAT as such:

```
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT('190404', 'YYMMDD')
```

Comment: Sorry my requirement is not that. I need a query to get the month end date. whenever this query is running it should give current month end date

Comment: Try `SELECT DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0))` to get the last day of the current month

Comment: Can you please give me the full query